# Prove that $P(x)=ax^3+bx+c$ has a root in $[0,2]$ given that: $9a+11b+29c=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Prove that $P(x)=ax^3+bx+c$ has a root in $[0,2]$ given that: $9a+11b+29c=0 ,(a,b,c\in \Bbb R)$

I tried to use intermediate value theorem:
$$P(0)=c,P(2)=8a+2b+c$$
But based on the given relation between coefficients we can't be sure that $P(0)P(2)<0$ , so I think problem statement is NOT correct,am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rewrite condition $9a+11b+29c=0$ like this:
$$ p(2)+3^3p({1\over 3}) +p(0)=0$$
So if $p(c) = 0$ for some $c\in \{0,{1\over 3},2\}$ we are done, else for some diffrent $a,b\in \{0,{1\over 3},2\}$, $p(a)$ and $p(b)$ have diferent sign and thus, since polynomial is countinius, $p$ must have zero point in $(a,b)\subset [0,2]$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $27P(1/3) = a + 9b + 27c$. Thus $27P(1/3) + P(0)+P(2) = 9a+11b+29c=0$. Then if any of $P(0)$, $P(1/3)$, or $P(2)$ is nonzero, at least one of the other two must be nonzero of the opposite sign, then we'd have a root by the intermediate value theorem. All that remains is to show that not all three of these are 0. But if all three of these are zero, then they are the three roots of $P$, so by [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), $0= 2\cdot\frac{1}{3} + 0\cdot \frac{1}{3}+0\cdot 2 = \frac{2}{3}$, contradiction. Thus this is impossible.